# Android - How to recreate Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

In my app, user can sign in with multiple accounts. With each session, user's data is difference. I use single activity.

So, how to recreate Hilt after user signed in for reload Use case, Repository, Data source? Or best practice using Hilt with multiple account?

Comment: This is a bit of a strange thing to ask, surely if you needed some data depending on a user, you would have a method like `getData(User)` in your repository? Hilt really has nothing to do with this?

Comment: Yes, I know way to get user's data. I'm using Hilt with layer use case, repository, data source with scope is SingletonComponent

```@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class RepositoryModule {
    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract fun bindAuthenticationRepository(repository: AuthenticationRepositoryImpl): AuthenticationRepository

}```

So, I don't know handle it for get data with dynamic user.

Comment: No that's not what I meant, I mean that if fetching data depends on the user, then you would pass the user as a parameter when fetching data? Not when injecting dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. But in my app, each user have specific database file. I need to connect the db after user signed in.
I use Hilt for get instance of db.

Comment: I see, well I've never seen anything like this, but maybe someone will have an idea. Good luck!

Comment: Thank @HenryTwist :D

Answer (score 1):

You can look for dependency scopes for Hilt. For your case, just use ActivityRetainedComponent on your AppModule. Add @ActivityRetainedScoped on your constructor class instead of singleton.

With this way, user's data create when activity created, and destroy when activity destroy.